# how can I serve static data (BeerCSS) from node_modules with sveltekit?

Tags: sveltekit

I want to serve static data stored in node_modules with sveltekit. I found a way to change the "static" directory (assets) but I was not able to ADD another directory (from node_modules) that is either mounted as subdirectory or served as overlay to "static".

any hints?